# Does ubuntu 18.04 LTS support ibus-m17n?

Tags: ibus

How to install ibus-m17n in Ubuntu 18.04LTS supported desktop?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is listed in the [packages list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ibus-m17n). You can install it with software center; command line method

```
sudo apt install ibus-m17n
```

After that add IBus to your startup applications:

- Open Startup Applications from the dash
- Add a new entry
- Give it a name
- In the command section type `ibus-daemon`
- Save it.

You probably need to log out and in for it to activate. You probably also need to install keyboard lay-outs and languages for your language.

Comment: Better than mine and more descriptive.  =)  +1